# How do I see my InMail statistics in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

I saw a post, *[InMail response rate](http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Inmail-response-rate-2524597.S.226930160)* - people are showing their InMail response rate. How do I see this?